# Saving into two different tables using two different stored procedures simultaneously in Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I have this Nested JSON which contain two Outer Objects (PtRegData And PartnerData). PtRegData is Single Record Data, on the other hand PtRegData most of the time has many records related to PtRegData. basically one to many relationship.

my JSON

```
{
"PtRegData": {
    "RecID": "1277",
    "filenum": "15090248",
    "FnameTxt": "Ahmad",
    "Snametxt": "Morsi",
    "Tnametxt": "abdul fattah",
    "Lnametxt": "Abu Maizer",
    "FilStatTxt": "2",
    "SexTxt": "1",
    "MarStatTxt": "4",
    "NatIDTxt": "18",
    "OcupID": "15",
    "SSnum": "6666888",
    "Passnum": "",
    "TelMob": "(88) 888-83333",
    "TelLnd": "",
    "TelInt": "",
    "TelWrk": "",
    "WrkExt": "",
    "autocomplete": "15549 Paramount Boulevard, Paramount, CA, United States",
    "Email": "embryologist85@gmail.com",
    "street_number": "12323",
    "route": "Dorothy Street",
    "AptNo": "22",
    "locality": "Los Angeles",
    "administrative_area_level_1": "CA",
    "postal_code": "90049",
    "country": "United States",
    "DobTxt": "12/31/1985",
    "AddrCtryID": "6",
    "AddrStateID": "1589",
    "PartnerData": [{
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PrtStatus": 1
    }, {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PrtStatus": 0
    }, {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PrtStatus": 0
    }]
}}
```

I use two different webmethods to process this data on the serverside as following

My Auto-Implementing Properties,

```
 Public Class PartnerData
    Public Property RecID As Integer
    Public Property PrtStatus As Integer
    Public Property ptfilenum As Integer
    Public Property prfilenum As Integer
End Class
Public Class PtRegData
    Public Property RecID As Integer
    Public Property filenum As Integer
    Public Property FnameTxt As String
    Public Property PartnerData As PartnerData()
End Class
Public Class TblReg
    Public Property PtRegData As PtRegData
End Class
```

For First Dataset, PtRegData

```
<WebMethod> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function TblRegRecHdlr(ByVal PtRegData As List(Of PtRegData))
    Try
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegDynRecHdlr", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PtRegData(0).RecID)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(PtRegData(0).RecID)
                End If
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PtRegData(0).filenum)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(PtRegData(0).filenum)
                End If
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PtRegData(0).FnameTxt)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PtRegData(0).FnameTxt
                End If
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using
                'Dim data = PtRegData(0).PartnerData
                'TblRegJoinRecHdlr(data)
                Dim jsondata As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
                Return jsondata ' I m returning value from SQL server, Crucial 
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

For Second Dataset PtRegData

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function TblRegJoinRecHdlr(ByVal Data) As List(Of PartnerData)
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegJoinDynHdlr", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            con.Open()
            For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).RecID)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).RecID)
                End If
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).ptfilenum)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).ptfilenum)
                End If
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).prfilenum)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).prfilenum)
                End If
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (Data(i).PrtStatus)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

How can I combine both Webmethods in one?

PS, the first record fires only once while the second one is a loop and needs to fire the stored procedure more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I combined them in this way

```html
<WebMethod> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function TblRegRecHdlr(ByVal PtRegData As List(Of PtRegData))
   Dim jsondata As String
    Try
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegDynRecHdlr", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PtRegData(0).RecID)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(PtRegData(0).RecID)
                End If
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PtRegData(0).filenum)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(PtRegData(0).filenum)
                End If
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PtRegData(0).FnameTxt)) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PtRegData(0).FnameTxt
                End If
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using
                jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
            End Using
         Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegJoinDynHdlr", con)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    Dim Data = PtRegData(0).PartnerData
                    con.Open()
                    For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).RecID)) Then
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                        Else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).RecID)
                        End If
                        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).ptfilenum)) Then
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                        Else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).ptfilenum)
                        End If
                        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).prfilenum)) Then
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
                        Else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).prfilenum)
                        End If
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (Data(i).PrtStatus)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Next
                    con.Close()
                End Using
                Return jsondata
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```